# how i can access api of one model into another

Tags: express, loopbackjs, strongloop

[image]Hello guys i m new to loopback. I go through all documentation as well as Google but haven't found any solution to my question.

My  question is that, if we can access one model into another for eg consider 2 model product and shop, if this both model does not have relation than we can export one model into another

eg:- code

```
module.exports = function(product ) {
 var Shop=app.models.shop;
};
```

Now main thing is that if we can call one model into another (as show above) than is it,  mean  we can call all rest api related to that model?

Why i want this thing suppose user fill all product as well as shop info through a single form (font end) then model of either shop or product is call. 
Suppose i call model shop in this model  i have to create a remote method to save product related info this thing i know so far.

So how i can use rest end point api of product to save data is this is not possible?

for eg:-

1. If we want to save shop detail then we call rest api like this `(get) api/shops`
2. If we want to save product detail then we call rest api like this `(get) api/products`

Now how i can call point 2 api into shop model is it possible then how if not, then why?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what you are asking here, but I'll take a stab. First off - you can call *any* API from your model code. It's just a HTTP end point so you can use a library like request() to call it.

However, you generally should not bother with a HTTP call to another LoopBack model when LoopBack provides a server-side API that does the same things the REST api does. So for ex, if you need to get all of one model type, or one object, or search, etc, that can all be done via local calls.

I'd start with the "Working with Data" docs: http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Working-with-data.html. It shows both REST and local Node API versions of working with your data.

Comment: i m try to upload image using product model i.e after all data save successfully to my table after that it upload image for that i m try to use container upload api in product model

Comment: Um - still not sure what you are saying. If you are asking about file uploads, then I'd look at the Storage component: http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Storage-component.html

Comment: from above image you can see i have input type="text" as well as  input type="file" try to save input data and file (save to server custom folder not in database. in database it just have file path url ) using model named as product . i have created a container as well

Comment: But your question is about accessing one model from another. If you are instead asking about how to associate a file with a model instance, then you need to edit your question quite a bit.

Comment: yes,both thing I want to know first problem is clear but now I stuck over hear https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49322580/upload-file-and-text-in-loopback would you help me in this it would be great