# upload file and text in loopback

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

Hello guys i m new too loopback, so don't know if it is possible or not

```
<form>
  <input type="text" id name="product">
  <input type="text" id name="productdesc">
  <input type="file" id name="product">
</form>
```

Demo image of form:

[image]

This demo form i m try to save to database  using model  rest api (model named as product)

**Note:** just try to save input text field and  file path url. i have created a container, using container i can easly upload a file to folder name as storage/file inside server folder.  hHow I can do that? Any suggestion would be great

Comment: So first off - you mention container - are you using the Storage component? (http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Storage-component.html)

Comment: @RaymondCamden yes I m using storage component

Comment: And... is it working? I'm a bit confused by what you've tried and how it is failing. If you haven't started at all, then obviously you should read the docs, and consider this post which has a full example: https://strongloop.com/strongblog/working-with-file-storage-and-loopback/

Comment: @RaymondCamden I m just want to save image to image folder and input data to database as show in above image using single url (API) from font end yes I go through documentation

Comment: Ok but you aren't providing enough information. If you read the docs, then you have enough information to get started. You should attempt to set it up and then let us know what went wrong. As I said, my blog entry above has a full example.

Comment: @RaymondCamden I just using create API to save data of input text and I know how to upload image using container/{file}/upload  API but don't know how to handle using single api and I haven't find any example which uses single API to save data as well as image

Comment: The blog entry I linked to literally shows that. It shows a model that includes 'regular' properties as well as a file one.

Comment: @RaymondCamden for you blog I found that you first upload file and then post  input field data am I right? I.e you are using 2 url am I correct?

Comment: Correct - as far as I know, you can't do it one. I suppose you could with a custom end point.

Comment: @RaymondCamden how that I was asking from start. if I m using custom end point then how call container or upload file is there anyway to upload file and save data

Comment: If you do a custom end point, then you would need to write code to process the uploaded file and form data and make the new relevant objects. That's the link I shared on your other question - the Node.js API for working with data. Personally I'd probably just use 2 http calls as my blog does (well, 3 as I have 2 file attachments).

Comment: @RaymondCamden thanks for helping me out and sorry for so many questions. one last question if I use 2 Ajax  method as you does on your example then how i can prevent multiple image upload from client  for eg :- suppose when user click on submit button then upload image to server after success response calls second Ajax method trigger which will post input data to server, now if validation or any other error occur that means user can upload one more image in server finally I have one useless image how I can prevent that

Comment: I'd disable the submit button click and only re-enable it on error or success. As for validation error, you can check for that BEFORE doing the file upload.